# react native fs library not writing files

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

when i use react-native-fs to create file, success in callback arrives but the file isn't in my android/data/com.myapp/files/test.txt library.

No errors in logcat so i'm wondering why my code with simple App.js not working.

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ToastAndroid
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
 // create a path you want to write to
 var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';
export default class App extends Component {
  onSave = () => {
    RNFS.writeFile(path, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'utf8')
.then((success) => {
 console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
})
.catch((err) => {
 console.log(err.message);
});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onSave()}>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

I need to write log.txt into the app folder but impossible to create new file.
I would appreciate every help or suggestion.

> react-native init myapp
>   cd myapp
>   yarn add react-native-fs
>   react-native link react-native-fs
>   react-native run-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try replacing *DocumentDirectoryPath* with *ExternalStorageDirectoryPath*.

Comment: Sure, i tried it but still the same problem. No errors only FILE WRITTEN shows in logcat.
EDIT: sorry i was taking a look into different directory. My file has been saved to root of internal storage but i thought that it is impossible to save files there. How to get to work DocumentDirectoryPath  ?

Comment: ExternalStorageDirectoryPath requires an aditional permmission: Isn't it better ExternalDirectoryPath?

Comment: This answer doesn't work with iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use try with `RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath`

> var url = path
> let fileName = path.split("/").pop()
> // console.log('fileName', fileName)
> var ext = this.extention(url);
> ext = "." + ext[0];
> const localFile = `${RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;
> // console.log('localFile', localFile)
>
> ```
>         const options = {
>             fromUrl: path,
>             toFile: localFile,
>             fileCache: true
>         };
>
>         if (await RNFS.exists(localFile)) {
>             FileViewer.open(localFile, { displayName: this.props.route.params.conversationSubject });
>         } else {
>             await RNFS.downloadFile(options).promise
>                 .then((res) => {
>                     // console.log('res', res)
>                     FileViewer.open(localFile);
>                 })
>                 .then((res) => {
>                     // success
>                     // console.log("success", res);
>                 })
>                 .catch(error => {
>                     // error
>                     console.log("Attachment open error: ", error);
>                 });
>         }
> ```